# How do I commit a git tag?

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

I have successfully made, committed, and pushed changes to a central git repository.  I realize now that I want to tag the current version of all files.  So I do:

```
git tag -a 0.5
```

That succeeds.  But now I try a `git push` and I am told there's nothing to commit.  How do I push my new tag to the central repository?

(Note that `git tag` shows the tag 0.5, but only locally)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do git tags get pushed as well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988088/do-git-tags-get-pushed-as-well)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you want

```
git push --tags
```

as that, well, pushes all your tags :)

There are some alternatives of course, this being git and all (replace origin with your repo of choice):

```
git push origin tag 0.5
```

or

```
git push origin refs/tags/0.5:refs/tags/0.5
```

See [git-push(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for further details. "[git ready](http://www.gitready.com/)" has some useful info in their [tagging](http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/03/tagging.html) article as well.

Comment: **Addendum:** if you create new commits on your branch, and then push (so there is something to transfer), git should detect all new tags that point to commits that are present after push on remote side, and push them too.

Comment: Default config git repos do not push tags that happen to exist on commits. Tags are only pushed if explicitly named or --tags used.

Answer (score 5):

Since [git 1.8.3 (April 22d, 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L131-L132), try a:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

When you push new commits, any tag referenced by those commits would be pushed as well.
In your case, any tag referenced by a commit *already* pushed should be pushed too.

That allows you to always use one command when pushing commits *and* tags.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing more information for a rather old question. Definitely worth my +1.