# Push git commits & tags simultaneously

Tags: git

`git push --tags` is a separate operation to `git push` since pushing tags should be a conscious choice to avoid accidentally pushing the wrong one. That's fine. But how do I push them both simultaneously / atomically? (`git push && git push --tags` is not perfectly atomic.)

Comment: What's your problem with `git push && git push --tags`?

Comment: Nothing in particular, it's just slower since the connection has to be established twice.

Comment: See my updated answer below: there is a new `--follow-tags` option since git 1.8.3

Comment: Another reason not to do these separately, is to avoid triggering two CI builds for the same commit, when you have that kind of automation in place.

Comment: also `--tags` does not distinguish between lightweight and annotated tags [source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

Comment: @fuz `git push && git push --tags` will trigger the CI pipeline twice, although this may have been irrelevant 10 years ago.

Comment: If all you care about is not triggering CICD twice, try `git push -o ci.skip && git push --tags`

Comment: @user1160006 — I hadn't heard about push options before. That's neat, but I think your command only works when using Gitlab?

Comment: @user1160006 I'll vote that up if you make it a real answer.  It's kind of a niche answer, but there are a lot of people using gitlab.

Comment:  Some CI tools determine if it's occurring a release or a pre-release by checking contextually that both commit and tag push

Answer (score 796, accepted):

## Update August 2020

As mentioned originally in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842917/6309) answer by [SoBeRich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8305572/soberich), and in my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28523050/6309), as of [git 2.4.x](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0e8e09cd8828b278a56d4ebfc52d662ff8038d8)

```
git push --atomic origin <branch name> <tag>
```

(Note: this actually [work with HTTPS only with Git 2.24](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37533655/6309))

## Update May 2015

As of [git 2.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219399/6309), you can do

```
git config --global push.followTags true
```

> If set to true enable --follow-tags option by default.
> You may override this configuration at time of push by specifying --no-follow-tags.

As noted in [this thread by Matt Rogers answering Wes Hurd](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAOjrSZv-D6qsyd7mjAEAJ=6YVUTUupYLNdUkDTjbGkA_9eOfUA@mail.gmail.com/):

`--follow-tags` **only pushes annotated tags**.

```
git tag -a -m "I'm an annotation" <tagname>
```

That would be pushed (as opposed to `git tag <tagname>`, a lightweight tag, which would not be pushed, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219399/6309))

## Update April 2013

Since [git 1.8.3 (April 22d, 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L155-L156), **you no longer have to do 2 commands to push branches, and then to push tags**:

> The new "`--follow-tags`" option tells "`git push`" to **push relevant annotated tags when pushing branches out**.

You can now try, when pushing new commits:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

That won't push *all* the local tags though, only the one referenced by commits which are pushed with the `git push`.

Git 2.4.1+ (Q2 2015) will introduce the option `push.followTags`: see "[How to make “`git push`” include tags within a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219399/6309)".

## Original answer, September 2010

The nuclear option would be `git push --mirror`, which will push all refs under `refs/`.

You can also push just one tag with your current branch commit:

```
git push origin : v1.0.0
```

You can combine the `--tags` option with a refspec like:

```
git push origin --tags :
```

(since `--tags` means: All refs under `refs/tags` are pushed, ***in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line***)

---

You also have this entry "[Pushing branches and tags with a single "git push" invocation](https://wincent.com/wiki/Pushing_branches_and_tags_with_a_single_%22git_push%22_invocation)"

> A handy tip was just posted to the [Git mailing list](https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_mailing_list) by Zoltán Füzesi:
>
> I use `.git/config` to solve this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = +refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*
```

> With these lines added `git push origin` will upload all your branches and tags. If you want to upload only some of them, you can enumerate them.
>
> Haven't tried it myself yet, but it looks like it might be useful until some other way of pushing branches and tags at the same time is added to git push.
> On the other hand, I don't mind typing:
>
> ```
> $ git push && git push --tags
> ```

**Beware**, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously/3745250#comment13613592_3745250) by [Aseem Kishore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132978/aseem-kishore)

`push = +refs/heads/*` will **force-pushes all your branches**.

> This bit me just now, so FYI.

---

[René Scheibe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2847174/ren%C3%A9-scheibe) adds [this interesting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously/3745250?noredirect=1#comment81576043_3745250):

> The `--follow-tags` parameter is misleading as only tags under `.git/refs/tags` are considered.
> If `git gc` is run, tags are moved from `.git/refs/tags` to `.git/packed-refs`. Afterwards `git push --follow-tags ...` does not work as expected anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm afraid `git push --tags :` doesn't work for me, but `git push origin --tags :` **did**. Not sure if that's a configuration thing on my end or a typo on yours.

Comment: @Will: more a typo on my side. I have fixed it in my answer.

Comment: The one comment on the post you link to correctly points out that the `push = +refs/heads/*` line *force*-pushes *all* your branches. This bit me just now, so FYI.

Comment: Re: the `--follow-tags` flag added in git 1.8.3, can I configure my git installation to make that the default?

Comment: @TrevorBurnham no, only the value of `push.default` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) can define default actions on push (`nothing`, `matching`, `upstream`, `simple` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309). You need to add `--follow-tag` explicitly.

Comment: @VonC What if I want to force push the tag? `git push --follow-tags -f` didn't work for me.

Comment: @user640378 not that I know of. I would force push a tag first, then do a classic `git push --follow-tags`

Comment: @MikeCampbellWhe it comes to tags (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging#Creating-Tags), I suspect this is to favor pushing annotated tags instead of lightweight ones.

Comment: It should be noted that if you have set `push.default=simple` in your git config, then `git push --follow-tags` doesn't work. In that case you still have to use `git push && git push --tags`.

Comment: @asmaier strange... you can find scripts out there (like https://github.com/davidheryanto/etc/blob/master/git.txt) which do set `push.default` to `simple`, *and* to a `push --follow-tags`. The tags on the (single) branch you are pushing should be take into account.

Comment: @VonC A coworker of mine just had that problem. Only after setting `push.default` to `matching` he could use `git push --follow-tags`. Before that it didn't work. The git version of him is 1.8.5.2.

Comment: @asmaier it would be interesting to see if that persists with a more recent git 2.1+ version.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham You can always create an alias shortcut in .profile or .bash_profile. `alias gpush='git push --follow-tags'` or `alias gpush='git push && git push --tags'` would allow you just run `gpush` at the command line to trigger whatever flavor push you want.

Comment: `--follow-tags` doesn't work with git 2.1.0. I have `push.default=simple`, which is the default.

Comment: @Suor Do you have an error message? Because that option is still in the newly released Git 2.3.5 (https://github.com/git/git/blob/52735a689270bb1de94eb3de198594b36caed9bb/Documentation/git-push.txt#L127-L131)

Comment: @Suor if the tags are already pushed, it wouldn't push them again.

Comment: @VonC they are not. Typical scenario I create a commit, I tag it, I do `git push --follow-tags`. Commit is pushed, tag is not.

Comment: @Suor then your tag is not an annotated tag, but a lightweight one. If it was annotated, it would be pushed as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74247/discussion-between-suor-and-vonc).

Comment: Remove the '+' if you don't want to force-push by default. (Hint: unless your remote repository really is supposed to mirror *everything* you do, yo do not.)

Comment: Could I do the same thing with `git pull`?

Comment: [remote "origin"] url  can only specify one repository? could it for all repositories. @Vonc

Comment: @netawater see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/6309 for multiple urls per remote.

Comment: @Vonc only skip url attribute, fetch & push are OK for tags.

Comment: Why isn't follow-tags the default? Are there any cases where you want to push changes but not tags?

Comment: @static_rtti yes, by default, Git does not presume that you want to push tags: you might have produced hundreds of them by mistake, or only one, for internel usage. Yet, with `git config --global push.followTags true`, you can make it the default for your repos.

Comment: @VonC : those cases seem quite contrived. I think for most users, the pricinple of least surpise implies that tags should be pushed by default.

Comment: @static_rtti I agree. I suspect this is mostly for historic reason. Again, for now, a global setting enable you to make that permanent, but yes, this is not the default yet.

Comment: The `--follow-tags` parameter is misleading as only tags under `.git/refs/tags` are considered. If `git gc` is run, tags are moved from `.git/refs/tags` to `.git/packed-refs`. Afterwards `git push --follow-tags ...` does not work as expected anymore.

Comment: @RenéScheibe Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Your link to "git 2.4.x" links to `git-config`, is that intentional?

Comment: @pepoluan That seems an error indeed. I have restore the proper link.

Comment: So does René Scheibe's "interesting comment" (as noted in the answer) mean that `git push` will stop pushing tags related to commits if `git gc` has been run? Doesn't that mean `--follow-tags` is partially broken, if it sometimes doesn't do its job based upon the history of the repository? (It's like `git commit` will make a commit, but not if you used to have a branch named `foo` and then deleted it.) Isn't that bug-filing-worthy? Or am misinterpreting the comment?

Comment: @GarretWilson I haven't experienced that issue. And I don't see it discussed on the [Git mailing list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:public-inbox.org/git+"git%20gc"+"tags"+"packed-refs").

Answer (score 25):

Since Git 2.4:

```
git push --atomic origin <branch name> <tag>
```

Comment: lol, I think I'd rather `git push; git push --tags`

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere lol, it’s not “simultaneous” and defies the question

Comment: why would you type all that out, when you could type something shorter, and achieve the same result?

Comment: Not the same.
Atomicity. There are a couple of articles on Wikipedia

Comment: Nope, this still triggers github workflows twice.

Answer (score 13):

Let's say you have created a new repo on github. So the first step would be to clone the repo:`git clone {Your Repo URL}`

You do your work, add some files, code etc., then push your changes with:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push
```

Now our changes are in main branch. Let's create a tag:

```
git tag v1.0.0                    # creates tag locally     
git push origin v1.0.0            # pushes tag to remote
```

If you want to delete the tag:

```
git tag --delete v1.0.0           # deletes tag locally    
git push --delete origin v1.0.0   # deletes remote tag
```

Comment: I tried your solution with git-2.21.0.windows.1 and found that 3 only pushes tag

Comment: I used "git commit -m "msg" in step 1 and there was no -a parameter. This could be why. Thank you for the followup!

Comment: @RajeshGupta it does NOT push to remote. Just locally to origin. Run `git status` after your three commands and you will see something like "your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit. (use "git push" to publish your local commits)"

Comment: @RajeshGupta actually what you suggested works (sorry for my last comment). But you have a little typo in step 3. It should be `git push origin 0.1.0` - you should omit the word 'tag'. Then it works really good. And for me even better than the --follow-tags option.

Comment: However I found another issue with this approach. I wondered why I can't see any related commit on develop branch. Then I noticed in Github UI --> "This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository."  This is strange. Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Just tested on git 2.31.0: `git push <refspec> --tags`. This has the advantage that it pushes ALL tags, not just annotated tags like `--follow-tags`.

Comment: This works! This needs to explicitly name both the remote and the branch name but at least it pushes all the work in a single shot

Answer (score 5):

To avoid triggering two CI builds for the same commit on Gitlab:

```
git push -o ci.skip && git push --tags
```

As suggested by [@user1160006 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously#comment119758843_3745135).

Comment: On gitlab it shows a pipeline, its just in the skipped state (which breaks pipeline badges). So it saves build ressources, but it doesn't allow to have a clean view of the pipeline's state.

Comment: Thankfully (at least in this context) I don't use pipeline badges, while on the other side I'm quite sensible to resorce usage, and even more to the time required to complete the pipeline actions, expecially if the second push triggers a deployment and I'm waiting for it's completion for a final "overall" test.
However @cglacet let me ask: while the first push sets the pileline to a skipped state, the second one which follow immediatly should restore the normal state, so it's just a temporary glitch

Comment: I would say the same, but for some reason badges are not taking the 2nd pipeline into account. Even when the 2nd pipeline succeed the badge shows the "unknown" tag (that I guess correspond to the skipped pipeline, or maybe its just because the commit triggered two pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Git GUI]

Git GUI has a PUSH button - pardon the pun, and the dialog box it opens has a checkbox for tags.

I pushed a branch from the command line, without tags, and then tried again pushing the branch using the `--follow-tags` option descibed above. The option is described as following annotated tags. My tags were simple tags.

I'd fixed something, tagged the commit with the fix in, (so colleagues can cherry pick the fix,) then changed the software version number and tagged the release I created (so colleagues can clone that release).

Git returned saying everything was up-to-date. It did not send the tags! Perhaps because the tags weren't annotated. Perhaps because there was nothing new on the branch.

When I did a similar push with Git GUI, the tags were sent.

[image: Tags sent with Git GUI]

For the time being, I am going to be pushing my changes to my remotes with Git GUI and not with the command line and `--follow-tags`.