# Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags

Tags: git

I have a local Git repo that I would like to push to a new remote repo (brand new repo set up on Beanstalk, if that matters).
My local repo has a few branches and tags, and I would like to keep all of my history.

It looks like I basically just need to do a `git push`, but that only uploads the `master` branch.

How do I push everything so I get a full replica of my local repo on the remote?

Answer (score 1268, accepted):

To push [all your branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---all), use either (replace REMOTE with the name of the remote, for example "origin"):

```
git push REMOTE '*:*'
git push REMOTE --all
```

To push [all your tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---tags):

```
git push REMOTE --tags
```

Finally, I think you can do this all in one command with:

```
git push REMOTE --mirror
```

However, in addition [`--mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---mirror), will also push your remotes, so this might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: `--all` instead of `*:*` seems more friendly

Comment: For some reason when using --mirror my local remote branches are listed as being pushed but don't actually appear in my repo. I have to first checkout all the remote/branches before using --mirror.

Comment: Just noting that `git push REMOTE --all` returned `No refs in common and none specified;` doing nothing., while `git push REMOTE "*:*` actually pushed all branches to remote.

Comment: Use --dry-run to inspect what will happen, in case you have "tmp" or "feature" branches locally that you don't really want to update in REMOTE

Comment: If the original remote is still available, it is a nice idea to do `git clone --mirror old-remote-url; cd repo.git; git push --mirror new-remote-url`.

Comment: On windows I'm required to use "*:*" instead.

Comment: --mirror is awesome! That's what I've been looking for. It allows you to clone from server A and then push the whole thing to new server B. --all only does the locally tracked branches - which makes it easy to lose work!

Comment: You make me feel pain. Why don't you use "RemoteName" or "origin" instead of yours "REMOTE".

Comment: `git push -u origin --mirror` worked for me when swapping from one remote to the next and getting all my branches that I hadn't locally checked out.

Comment: The recommendation from @Jonno first to use --dry-run is very smart. An example of the pain it can help you avoid: git push --mirror can change your remote in ways that can't be undone, a rare power in git. (See the [related excerpt from the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_options_a_id_options_a) `--mirror [...] Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end.`)

Comment: what do you mean by "push your remotes"?  what are `your remotes` and why could it be a bad thing?

Comment: i'm not sure, but it looks like `git push REMOTE --all` only pushes the local branches to REMOTE, where `git push REMOTE '*:*'` pushes local branches *and* other remote branches to the remote. Again I'm not sure if I'm understanding this right, but there is definitely a difference between `--all` and `'*:*'`

Comment: `git push REMOTE '*:*'` seems to push tags too, whereas it looks like `--all` does not.

Comment: git push --all does NOT push branches on the original remote (git branch -r) unless they are checked out locally. This should be combined with the answer below to have a complete answer.

Comment: It's worth mentioning `git push --follow-tags` and `git config --global push.followTags true`. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/9638388

Comment: the difference is that `--all` will push only branches that are locally checked out, while `*:*` will push all the branches from source origin to destination origin aka full clone including tags

Comment: Do not do `git push REMOTE --mirror`, it deleted all branches. its mess.

Comment: @Chandra You can find accidentally deleted refs using the reflog command.

Answer (score 230):

In the case like me that you aquired a repo and are now switching the remote origin to a different repo, a new empty one...

So you have your repo and all the branches inside, but you still need to checkout those branches for the `git push --all` command to actually push those too.

You should do this before you push:

```
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v master `; do git checkout --track $remote ; done
```

Followed by

```
git push --all
```

Comment: Strangely, `git push '*:*'` pushed all branches. `git push -all` just pushed the master. I was transporting repo from github to bitbucket.

Comment: Instead of checking out every single branch you should just do "git branch --track $remote". In huge repos checking out an old branch takes sometime

Comment: I had to make a small change for this to work: `--track remotes/$remote` instead of `--track $remote`. Here's the complete command line: `for remote in \`git branch -r | grep -v master \`; do git checkout --track remotes/$remote ; done`

Comment: I allowed the master branch(s) by removing `grep -v master`. I started with a bare repo, and some repos have multiple branches with master in their name (i.e. master-next).

Comment: I found this question as a result of trying to sync two remote repositories that were clones back together. My team had moved from github to gitlab while work was suddenly introduced during the transition that relied on our old github CI pipeline. After that work concluded, we wanted to basically import a second time from github to gitlab without losing our gitlab progress. This worked better for me than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 112):

Here is another take on the same thing which worked better for the situation I was in. It solves the problem where you have more than one remote, would like to clone all branches in remote `source` to remote `destination` but without having to check them all out beforehand.

(The problem I had with Daniel's solution was that it would refuse to checkout a tracking branch from the `source` remote if I had previously checked it out already, ie, it would not update my local branch before the push)

```
git push destination +refs/remotes/source/*:refs/heads/*
```

> Note:
>   If you are not using direct CLI, you must escape the asterisks:
>
> `git push destination +refs/remotes/source/\*:refs/heads/\*`
>
> - [@mattalxndr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334966/mattalxndr)

this will push all branches in remote `source` to a head branch in `destination`, possibly doing a non-fast-forward push. You still have to push tags separately.

Comment: +1 This worked for me, cloning from one `remote` to another. Thanks!

Comment: I had to escape the asterisks: `git push destination +refs/remotes/source/\*:refs/heads/\*`

Comment: For me, this wound up pushing a branch called HEAD, which I don't think is intentional in this scenario.

Comment: Excellent answer. I did however have problems with `refs/remotes/source/*` matching the `tags` sub-name, which then created remote _branches_ with names like `tags/version-1.0` in the target-repository, which then had to be cleaned-up.  This problem might be a specific to my remotes, I don't know.

Comment: This answer was incredibly useful to me. The only mention in the git-push(1) man page of this use of asterisks is in a tiny example for the `--prune` option.

Comment: Excellent answer, far different than the usual `--mirror` parameter everybody recommends. Works perfectly for scenarios where you just want to keep sync'd two remotes for automation or auditing purposes.

Comment: That is a super useful answer! Thank you sir!

Comment: Thankyou, this works where `git push origin *:*` did not,  without a `git clone --bare` or `git clone --mirror`  and without a loop to materialize all the remote branches.  Final commands for moving a repository:
1) `git clone oldurl` 
2) `git remote set-url origin newurl`
3) `git push -u origin --tags 'refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*' `

Comment: ```git push newremote --tags refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*``` will push the tags at the same time.

Comment: +1, I just had to remove the `+` before `refs` because I don't want to force remote update and possibly do something destructive.

Answer (score 35):

**Mirroring a repository**

Create a bare clone of the repository.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
```

Mirror-push to the new repository.

```
cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Remove the temporary local repository you created in step 1.

```
cd ..
rm -rf old-repository.git
```

**Mirroring a repository that contains Git Large File Storage objects**

Create a bare clone of the repository. Replace the example username with the name of the person or organization who owns the repository, and replace the example repository name with the name of the repository you'd like to duplicate.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
```

Navigate to the repository you just cloned.

```
cd old-repository.git
```

Pull in the repository's Git Large File Storage objects.

```
git lfs fetch --all
```

Mirror-push to the new repository.

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Push the repository's Git Large File Storage objects to your mirror.

```
git lfs push --all https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Remove the temporary local repository you created in step 1.

```
cd ..
rm -rf old-repository.git
```

Above instruction comes from Github Help: https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for adding `git lfs` as well.

Answer (score 29):

This is the most concise way I have found, provided the destination is empty. Switch to an empty folder and then:

```
# Note the period for cwd >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> v
git clone --bare https://your-source-repo/repo.git .
git push --mirror https://your-destination-repo/repo.git
```

Substitute `https://...` for `file:///your/repo` etc. as appropriate.

Answer (score 24):

In my case what worked was.

```
git push origin --all
```

Comment: Simple and easy. It works! `origin` is alias for remote URL Git repository.

Answer (score 16):

The manpage for `git-push` is worth a read. Combined with [this website](https://wincent.com/wiki/Pushing_branches_and_tags_with_a_single_%22git_push%22_invocation) I wrote the following in my `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = …
    fetch = …
    push = :
    push = refs/tags/*
```

The `push = :` means "push any 'matching' branches (i.e. branches that already exist in the remote repository and have a local counterpart)", while `push = refs/tags/*` means "push all tags".

So now I only have to run `git push` to push all matching branches and all tags.

Yes, this is not quite what the OP wanted (all of the branches to push must already exist on the remote side), but might be helpful for those who find this question while googling for "how do I push branches and tags at the same time".

Answer (score 15):

My favorite (and simplest) way

```
git clone --mirror  OLD_GIT_URL
cd  NEW_CREATED_FOLDER
git remote add NEW-REMOTE NEW_GIT_URL
git push  NEW-REMOTE --mirror
```

Answer (score 13):

Run following to move existing repository to new remote with all branches and tags:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin git@<repo-url.git>
for remote in `git branch -r `; do git checkout --track remotes/$remote ; done
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Answer (score 8):

I found above answers still have some unclear things, which will mislead users. First, It's sure that `git push new_origin --all` and `git push new_origin --mirror` can't duplicate all branches of origin, it just duplicate your local existed branches to your new_origin.

Below is two useful methods I have tested:

1,duplicate by clone bare repo.`git clone --bare origin_url`, then enter the folder, and `git push new_origin_url --mirror`.By this way, you can also use `git clone --mirror origin_url`, both `--bare`and `--mirror` will download a bare repo,not including workspace. please refer [this](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/)

2,If you have a git repo by using `git clone`, which means you have bare repo and git workspace, you can use `git remote add new_origin new_origin_url`, and then `git push new_origin +refs/remotes/origin/\*:refs/heads/\*`,and then `git push new_origin --tags`

By this way, you will get a extra head branch, which make no sense.

Answer (score 7):

I was in a process of switching from one version control service to another and needed to clone all repositories including all branches, tags and history.

To achieve above I did next:

- manually checkout all branches to local repository (script to checkout all shown below),
- `git push origin '*:*'`

.sh script used to checkout all branches to local repository:

```
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
   git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin/} $branch
done
```

Answer (score 5):

To push branches and tags (but not remotes):

```
git push origin 'refs/tags/*' 'refs/heads/*'
```

This would be equivalent to combining the `--tags` and `--all` options for `git push`, which git does not seem to allow.

Comment: Is there an additional option to push from another remote ? For instance with `+refs/remotes/source/*`

Answer (score 5):

I found the best and simplest method https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/git-push-all-branches-new-remote, works like a charm for me, it will push all the tags and branches from origin to the new remote:

```
git remote add newremote new-remote-url

git push newremote --tags refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

I used 'git push --all -u newremote', but it only push the checkouted branches to the newremote.

> Git: Push All Branches to a New Remote
>
> by Keith Dechant , Software Architect
>
> Here's a scenario some of you might have encountered with your Git
> repositories. You have a working copy of a Git repo, say from an old
> server. But you only have the working copy, and the origin is not
> accessible. So you can't just fork it. But you want to push the whole
> repo and all the branch history to your new remote.
>
> This is possible if your working copy contains the tracking branches
> from the old remote (origin/branch1, origin/branch1, etc.). If you do,
> you have the entire repo and history.
>
> However, in my case there were dozens of branches, and some or all of
> them I had never checked out locally. Pushing them all seemed like a
> heavy lift. So, how to proceed?
>
> I identified two options:
>
> Option 1: Checkout every branch and push I could do this, and I could
> even write a Bash script to help. However, doing this would change my
> working files with each checkout, and would create a local branch for
> each of the remote tracking branches. This would be slow with a large
> repo.
>
> Option 2: Push without changing your working copy There is a second
> alternative, which doesn't require a checkout of each branch, doesn't
> create extraneous branches in the working copy, and doesn't even
> modify the files in the working copy.
>
> If your old, no-longer-active remote is called "oldremote" and your
> new remote is called "newremote", you can push just the remote
> tracking branches with this command:
>
> `git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/*:refs/heads/*`
>
> In some
> cases, it's also possible to push just a subset of the branches. If
> the branch names are namespaced with a slash (e.g.,
> oldremote/features/branch3, oldremote/features/branch4, etc.), you can
> push only the remote tracking branches with names beginning with
> "oldremote/features":
>
> `git push newremote refs/remotes/oldremote/features/*:refs/heads/features/*`
>
> Whether you
> push all the branches or just some of them, Git will perform the
> entire operation without creating any new local branches, and without
> making changes to your working files. Every tracking branch that
> matches your pattern will be pushed to the new remote.
>
> For more information on the topic, check out this thread on Stack
> Overflow.
>
> Date posted: October 9, 2017

Comment: Hi but doing this also adds to you repo a HEAD brach that was not in the previous commit, do you know how to deal with that ?

Comment: Yeah, I also found that, I didn't do anything to it yet. You can delete it directly.

Answer (score 4):

To push all branches on your remote you just need to commit all branches first and then try below command

```
git push --all your-remote-branch-name
```

Like

```
git push --all origin(my remote name)
```

Hope it will help(:

Answer (score 3):

Based in [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662605/daniel) answer I did:

```
for remote in \`git branch | grep -v master\`
do 
    git push -u origin $remote
done
```

Comment: Even better, `| grep -v master` can be replaced with `| sed 's/\*//'` (I'm assuming you excluded `master` to avoid the nasty little `*` that's prepended to the currently selected branch) which allows you to include `master` and avoid any problems when `master` is not your currently selected branch. Also sorry for necroposting, it's just that this answer helped me today and I wanted to share my modification if it can help others in my position...

Answer (score 3):

Below command will push all the branches(*including the ones which you have never checked-out but present in your git repo, you can see them by `git branch -a`*)

**`git push origin '*:*'`**

> NOTE: This command comes handy when you are migrating version control
>   service(*i.e migrating from **Gitlab** to **GitHub***)

Comment: Migrating between version control services and this is exactly what i'm searching for, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The main way to do what you want is to use the [`--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all) **and** [`--tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---tags) flags. Leaving out either will not push part of what you want. Unfortunately, they cannot be used together (don't see why) so they must be run one after the other.

```sh
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Another option that is relevant is the [`--prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---prune) option that removes any branches/tags on the remote that don't exist locally.

Alternatively, consider the [`--mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror) option as it is basically equivalent to `--all --tags --prune`.

```sh
git push --mirror
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that none of these seemed to work properly for me. Feel free to flame this to death but for some reason couldn't get the other options to work properly.

Expected result was a repo "cloned" to another remote (ie from Github to another provider):

- All branches are created on new remote
- All branch history are created on new remote

  - (this was missed on every solution I tried)
- All tags are created on new remote
- Source moves over (a given)
- Non-destructive (giving pause to the --mirror option)

The major issue I was seeing was either all remote branches didn't get recreated in the new remote. If a command did, the new remote did not have the branch history (ie doing a `git checkout branch; git log` wouldn't show the expected branch commits).

I noticed `git checkout -b branchname` is NOT the same as `git checkout branchname` (the latter being what I needed). I notice `git checkout --track branchname` didn't appear to pull the branch history.

**My Solution** (powershell based):

```powershell
Function Git-FetchRemoteBranches {
$originalbranch = (git symbolic-ref HEAD).split("/")[-1]

Foreach ($entry in (git branch -r)) {

If ($entry -like "*->*") {
  $branch = $entry.split("->")[2].split("/")[1]
}
  else {$branch = $entry.split("/")[1]}

Write-Host "--Trying git checkout " -NoNewline
Write-Host "$branch" -Foreground Yellow

git checkout $branch

Remove-Variable branch -Force

""}

#Switch back to original branch, if needed
If ( ((git symbolic-ref HEAD).split("/")[-1]) -ne $originalbranch) {
"Switching back to original branch"
git checkout $originalbranch
Remove-Variable originalbranch -Force
}
}

git clone http://remoterepo
cd remoterepo
Git-FetchRemoteBranches
git remote add newremote
git push newremote --all
git push newremote --tags #Not sure if neeeded, but added for good measure
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is What I solved **[remote rejected]** when I push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags

- git clone --mirror *old-repo*
- cd <name-repo.git>
- git remote add **new** *new-repo*
- git push **new** --mirror

Answer (score 0):

Every time I Google how to do this I end up reading this same thread, but it doesn't get me where I need to be, so hopefully this will help my future self and others too.

I started a new local project that I want to push to my repo (BitBucket). Here is what I did:

1. navigate to my local project root
2. initiate with: `git init`
3. add all files with: `git add .`
4. commit with: `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
5. go to my repo (BitBucket)
6. create new repository: `new_project`
7. go back to my local project
8. add the remote with: `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:AndrewFox/new_project.git`
9. push the commit with: `git push origin master -f`

The `-f` flag is to force the push, otherwise it will identify that the two repo's are different and fail.

Comment: This is not what the original question was asking about. This is also really unsafe. You're telling people to throw away old commits. You should really basically never use the "force" option unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @CameronTacklind this is for a new project, so there are no commits.

Comment: The original question is asking about how to upload an **existing** project to a "new remote" **and** include *all* branches & tags. The "new remote" is empty and thus would not need a force. Again, you should basically never do a force push unless you really know what you're doing. Suggesting this to other users, especially without appropriate warnings, in particular for a case that doesn't need it, is going to hurt someone.

Comment: Fair point. I got these instructions from the BitBucket website and decided to share. Please edit my answer to include your warnings and potential issues, as I’m not as familiar as you are with it. Thank you for bringing this to my attention 