# Tags on a git repo not in the ancestry of master: How to "merge the latest tag into the master branch"?

Tags: git, github, git-tag

I deleted and recreated the same repository on GitHub (please, don't ask why).
From my "old" local repository I pushed all tags following [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags) S.O. question.
Now I have all tags there, but only the 2 commits made after.

How can I make the tags appear as it were been committed?

If I view a tag, let's say "1.8", I see a bunch of commits.

I would like to have into the new repo **only** the single commits that were previously tagged.

**Question UPDATED:**

**from a comment below, by Charlie:
"tags are commits, just not in the ancestry of master"**

**How to "merge the latest tag into the master branch" ?**

Comment: Pushing a commit also pushes all of its parents.

Comment: ok thanks. Any hint on how to make the tags appear as commits?

Comment: I'm guessing that [this](https://github.com/dentex/ytdownloader/) is the repository you're talking about. Your tags are commits, just not in the ancestry of master. You could rebase master on top of your latest tag (rewriting history with pushed commits, can be dangerous so be careful) or merge the latest tag into the master branch (which is safer & easier,but your commit history would be a bit weird)

Comment: As far as getting your history to only single tagged commits, recreating the repository again, you might be able to use an interactive rebase to squash your history between tags down, but that would involve re-tagging everything as you would effectively be creating a new history.

Comment: Right guess ;) "merge the latest tag into the master branch" is what I'm going to try. Thanks. I tried `git rebase -i` but I got a hell of files to fix on every squash trial.