# gitlab :import existing repository .not working correctly

Tags: repository, gitlab

Here is the details of my setup:

Gitlab version: 5.2
Operating System: Centos 6.3
I am Importing an existing repository while creating a new project(/projects/new)  .

A new EMPTY project is created  however no repository is imported and no error message comes up. While I was digging around I found this in my puma.stderr.log.

```
=== puma startup: 2013-06-13 15:37:53 +0530 ===
error: Couldn't resolve host 'github.com' while accessing https://github.com/<username>/tester.git/info/refs
```

This GitLab installation is behind a HTTP proxy server and it seems like the proxy settings aren’t configured. But, my /etc/profile.d/ has a script that sets the proxy system wide with variables http_proxy and https_proxy.

On further investigation I checked whether the problem could be with gitlab-shell unable to reach out to the URL via the proxy and I tried the following.

```
$./bin/gitlab-projects import-project xxx/tester_test_test.git https://github.com/<username>/tester.git
```

This seems to work perfectly.

It seems like Puma does not use this gitlab-shell and is trying to reach out to the URL. Which leads me to the question, how do I tell PUMA about my proxy server?

Following is my production.log

```
Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 170.95.35.204 at 2013-06-13 16:20:00 +0530
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"favicon.ico"}
  Rendered public/404.html (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :project rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
Started GET "/projects/new" for 170.95.35.204 at 2013-06-13 16:20:04 +0530
Processing by ProjectsController#new as HTML
  Rendered projects/_errors.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered projects/new.html.haml within layouts/application (4.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_search.html.haml (57.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head_panel.html.haml (60.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_dashboard.html.haml (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 72ms (Views: 65.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)``
```

Answer (score 2):

When encountering gitlab import problems, this is a general workaround.

1. Create a bare project in gitlab
2. Add it as a remote in an existing cloned [and up to date] repo.   You can git fetch from your current origin to bring it up to date.

   git remote add mygitlab  [bare project URL from #1]
3. Push the existing repo state to the new remote

   git push mygitlab --all

You may want to check some of the various recipes here if you have a problem getting *everything* to push: [Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)

4. I myself just edit .git/config by hand.   Take the mygitlab URL and make it the origin url.   You can just delete the mygitlab block, or via command line:

   git remote remove mygitlab

This is easier than banging rocks together trying to get gitlab to import something it doesn't want to [for me, it's bitbucket right now].