# Android Studio VCS won't push my new branch to Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, android-studio

In my Android Studio project, I had one branch called `myproj`.

I've been updating and committing to it for a few days. I decided I wanted to work on a new feature and I'm not sure where it will take me so I created a new `branch`.

When I committed and pushed my new changes however, it seems to have only committed it locally but didn't push it. When I go to my Git repository it still says I have one branch.

How do I push this new branch to Git?

Comment: you can push the branch in terminal(command prompt) by using this command 'git push origin yourbranchname'

Comment: Are you in a detached HEAD mode? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309). What does `git branch` returns?

Comment: `git branch` returns `myproj \n * new_branch`

Comment: use this command 'git remote -v' and tell me what it is showing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push the branch in terminal (command prompt) by using following command

- `git push origin yourbranchname`

  origin - your remote URL

  yourbranchname - the branch which you want to push

Answer (score 0):

(Used this approach to push branches to GITHUB. Hope this works same on others repo and private hostings as well.)

I opened git in terminal and typed:

```
git push --all
```

Then:

Press Enter.

Enter credentials.

Done.

Comment: Further detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags