# Gitorious upgrade from 2.0.0 to 3.1.1

Tags: git, upgrade, gitorious

We have a Gitorious installation that is used as the main code repository and runs on 2.0.0 When we attempted to use the upgrade path outlined in https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Upgrading we had problems because the original installation appears to be unable to upgrade to 2.0 -> 2.1

We have also attempted to clone the code from the original installation, change the origin in the .git/config file and push to the new gitorious installation. Although this works there are a couple of problems:

1. Some of the history is lost
2. Only a single branch is pushed to the new repository
3. We have about 150 different projects

Has anyone had success with upgrading Gitorious from 2.0 -> 2.1 or pulling large numbers of repositories from one version of gitorious and pushing them to a later version.

Comment: just setup a new installation (... i would switch to gitlab if i where you) pull the repository, and then just push to the new. this will push the complete history.  `git remote set-url <new url>`

Comment: I tried this but only the branch i pulled gets pushed to the new repository - any idea how I get all branches from one to the other?

Comment: this is normal git behaviour. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags

Comment: OK that looks good - any ideas how to extract the list of URL's from gitorious so I can automate this

Comment: https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Api dont know since which version this is supported.

Comment: Looks like thats supported on our old system - thats fantastic, I'm sure I can do something to automate it all now. Post this as the answer and I'll accept it - You've saved me a massive amount of time - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just setup a new installation, pull the repository, and then just push to the new. this will push the complete history. `git remote set-url <new url>`

for further reference see:
[Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)
https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Api