# Wrong(?) branch prefixes migrating SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn

I basically followed [this howto](http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git) to migrate an old, very big SVN repository to git. This does not work as expected. Here is an example excerpt from my checkout living in `~/git/old_svn_repo` (done with `git svn` but without `--no-metadata`):

```
remotes/origin/trunk
remotes/origin/branchX
remotes/origin/branchY # and many more
```

Next step is step 4, which seemed to work flawlessly. I pushed to the bare repository (note I used `~/git/new-bare.git` instead of `~/new-bare.git`):

```
git init --bare ~/git/new-bare.git
cd ~/git/new-bare.git
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk
cd ~/git/old_svn_repo
git remote add bare ~/git/new-bare.git
git config remote.bare.push 'refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*'
git push bare
```

This got me a lot of output like

```
* [new branch]      origin/trunk -> origin/trunk
* [new branch]      origin/foo-> origin/foo
* [new branch]      origin/bar-> origin/bar
```

Next is step 5 where you are supposed to rename `trunk` to `master`:

```
cd ~/git/new-bare.git
git branch -m trunk master
```

Here the problem starts:

I enter:

```
git branch -m trunk master
```

I get:

```
error: refname refs/heads/trunk not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

Doing `git branch -a` reveals that all branches are prefixed with `origin/`.

What did I do incorrectly here and how do I get that right?

Comment: Are you working on the repo that's supposed to be the remote or your local?

Comment: I did a git-svn clone like described in the linked howto and am now trying to copy it to a new bare repository as an in-between step to get it onto a gitlab.

Comment: It really looks as if you haven't cd'd into old_svn_repo before setting the bare remote and running the push

Comment: I achieved what I want with a different approach, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through SO some more, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags), and the answer by Pieter Breed. So I tried it, from the directory I cloned the SVN repository into:

```
cd ~/git/old_svn_repo
git remote add new_gitlab_server ssh://git@mygitlab.example.com/foo/bar.git
git push new_gitlab-server +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

and poof, everything appeared on my Gitlab as expected without the intermediate step creating a local bare repo.

Now, "master" is still called "trunk" which is OK, but leads to `warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.` on the first clone, so I did the following:

```
git clone ssh://git@mygitlab.example.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
git checkout trunk
git checkout -b master
git push -u origin master
```

It seems the tags were converted to branches, but we can live with that.

Edit: To convert SVN tag branches into Git tags:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags | cut -d / -f 4 |
while read ref
do
 git tag -a "$ref" -m "Tag: $ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
 git branch -D "tags/$ref";
done
```

Answer (score 6):

After several failed attempts at this (I had the same issue, an extra directory named origin in the refs/remotes path.) I made it work with this minor tweak.

```
git config remote.bare.push 'refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*'
```

Additionally in the create .gitignore step I used:

```
git svn show-ignore -i origin/trunk > .gitignore
```

Which worked as intended.

I'm not sure where the extra origin dir comes from in this, but these mods worked for me.

Comment: Adding origin to the path in the git config command fixed my problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FYI this is happening because you're using a different version of git. When I run git/1.8.3.1 the git svn command creates refs/remotes/trunk, but when I run git/2.8.3 it creates refs/remotes/origin/trunk. At some point between these two releases of git the git svn functionality was changed to add "/origin/" into the branch refs.

The referenced article was written in 2010. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git#Releases, the git released in 2010 was git/1.7, whereas git/2.8 was released in 2016. Thus, the author of the article used an older git than what OP is probably using. Changing the refspec to add "/origin/" works fine for me. An alternative would be to use an older version of git.

You can run `git show-ref` to see the refspec when your git svn command finishes.