# How can I push all branches and tags to a new remote repository?

Tags: git

I've cloned a remote repository `A` to a local repo `A'`. `A'` has 10 branches and only `master` is checked out. Now `A` is unavailable and a new remote repository `B` has been created. I want to push all the branches and tags from `A'` to `B`.

To my knowledge, I can only push the checked-out branch(`master` in this case) to the remote repository. Is there a simple way in which I can push all the branches and tags? I have quite a number of local repositories like `A'` and I don't want to checkout the branches one by one.

Comment: Please write this in English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+all+branches+tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the old repository url is `https://gitlab.com/foo/oldbar.git` and the new one is `https://gitlab.com/foo/newbar.git`.

```
cd local_repo
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/foo/newbar.git
git push origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

In case you have unpushed commits on `master`,

```
git pull origin -r master
git push origin -u master
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new remote to your local repo, and push the branches there... and it can be done without checking out anything:

```
git remote add new-repo the-url-to-repo
git push new-repo branch-a branch-b v1.0 v2.0
```

And so on

Comment: I got errors: error: src refspec branch-a does not match any.

Comment: Sure... try with your own branches and tags (like master and stuff).... those are just examples.

Comment: Yes, I used my branches. the full errors:     error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://*******.git'

Comment: Are you working on a _new_ repo? That has to be done on the local repo where you already have those branches.