# How to migrate a Bitbucket repository to Github?

Tags: git

I want to migrate an old Bitbucket repository, containing multiple branches, to Github. To accomplish this, I've followed [this](https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/how-to-migrate-from-bitbucket-to-github-75c87a892767) description:

```
# add remote github repository
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com:USER/PROJECT.git
# push all branches <-- doesn't work
$ git push upstream master
$ git push --tags upstream
```

Only the `master` branch is pushed to the Github repository (also for `git push --all upstream`).

In order to push all branches to Github, I need to `checkout` them individually and do `git push upstream`.

How can I push all branches to Github without first `checkout` them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the below steps.

1. Mirror the source repo.

   `git clone --mirror https://url-of-the-source-git-repo.git`
2. Go to the newly cloned repo

   `cd to-your-git-repo-folder.git`
3. set the new remote url.

   `git remote set-url --push origin https://url-of-the-destination-git-repo.git`
4. Push to the new repo

   `git push --mirror`

By following these commands you will migrate to new repo with all the branches and commits.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be working. Since I'm new to Git, does this make a "hard" copy of the Bitbucket repository on Github, or does it create a "soft" copy, where only references are copied, such that the Github repository references the Bitbucket repository, but doesn't actually contains the files itself?

Comment: This is going to copy the actual files not the references, you can start working on new repository after migration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using this single command.

```
git push REMOTE --mirror
```

You can read more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for anyone stumbling across this that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58803996/6325894) only changes the remote for `git push`. Thus, when you fetch or pull, it will still be referencing the original repository on BitBucket.

In order to avoid this, simply drop the `--push` when setting the remote url:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:org/my_repository.git
```

For the full process:

```
git clone --mirror git@bitbucket.org:org/my_bitbucket_repository.git

cd my_bitbucket_repository.git

git remote set-url origin git@github.com:org/my_github_repository.git

git push --mirror
```

You can then verify this has actually changed the remote by:

```
git remote show origin
```

Which will output something similar to this:

```
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:org/my_github_repository.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:org/my_github_repository.git
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branches:
    main    tracked
  Local refs will be mirrored by 'git push'
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have [fetched all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches).

```
git fetch --all
```

Then [push all branches to the new remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)

```
git push upstream --all
```

Comment: It still just push a single branch (`master`). It should be noted that I've never worked on the other branches locally before. It's an old Bitbucket repository that I cloned recently.