# Split a subdirectory to its own repository using git filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo, filter-repo

I am following this: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository

I have a repository called `my-repo`

The structure of the directories below it is as:

```
MyProject
   |
   ------ UI
   |
   ------ DB
   |
   ------ SERVER
   |
   ------ ANDROID
```

I want to split `ANDROID` directory above into its own new repository called `my-repo-android`

I did the following for it:

1. Cloned the repository

   ```
   git clone git@bitbucket.org:myproject/my-repo.git
   ```
2. Go into that directory:

   ```
   cd my-repo
   ```
3. Remove origin to avoid any push by mistake

   ```
   git remote rm origin
   ```
4. Run filter repo command

   ```
   git filter-repo --path MyProject/ANDROID --path-rename ANDROID/:
   ```

The command runs successfully. However, instead of getting the root directory as `ANDROID`, I still see the directory as `MyProject/ANDROID` with everything else removed.

What am I doing wrong?

How to use `filter-repo` `path-rename` option correctly so that the project structure changes from `MyProject\ANDROID` to directly `ANDROID` directory at the root ?

Edit:

The following command as per comments and answer below worked:

```
git filter-repo --path MyProject/ANDROID/ --path-rename MyProject/ANDROID/:ANDROID/
```

After this, I created a new repository remotely and ran the following commands:

1. Add remote origin

   ```
   git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:mypronect/androidRepo.git
   ```
2. Master branch

   ```
   git branch -M master
   ```
3. Pull first

   ```
   git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
   ```
4. Push

   ```
   git push -u origin master
   ```

Now I can see `ANDROID` directory correctly on the new `androidRepo` on bitbucket.

And when I open any file, I can see the history as well. Thus `filter-repo` has worked as expected.

However, I only see `master` branch. I do not see any of the other historical branches and tags. (We tag/create a separate branch for every release we do).

What am I missing? How can I preserve all branches and tags related to `ANDROID` as well ?

I tried the following command, but it didn't work:

```
 git push --all origin
```

Comment: does the `--path-rename` in your actual command target `ANDROID/` or `MyProject/ANDROID/` ?

Comment: @LeGEC: Sorry I am new to this. What do you mean by that ? Instead of `MyProject/ANDROID`, I want `ANDROID` as my root directory in the resultant repository..

Comment: then can you try : `--path-rename MyProject/ANDROID:ANDROID` ?

Comment: @LeGEC: That worked. Can you please check my updated question above. Its the very last issue I am facing. I want to preserve branch history and tag history as well. But with what I have done, I only see master branch remotely.

Comment: All good. Found the answer. I was using the --all flag incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `MyProject` before `ANDROID` in the `--path-rename` option. With

1. `--path MyProject/ANDROID` you are telling `filter-repo` to keep only the path `MyProject/ANDROID` folder.
2. `--path-rename ANDROID/:` you are converting the `ANDROID` folder to the root folder basically.

My guess is that you `filter-repo` is not finding `ANDROID` folder, because it is inside `MyProject`, and therefore it is not able to rename it.

Final command might be:

```
git filter-repo --path MyProject/ANDROID/ --path-rename MyProject/ANDROID/:
```

Or, the corresponding shortcut:

```
git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter=MyProject/ANDROID
```

---

**EDIT**: I thought you wanted to make the **content** of the `ANDROID` folder as the root, instead it seems you want to move the `ANDROID` folder from `./MyProject` to `./`. In this case @LeGEC gets the point with `--path-rename MyProject/ANDROID:ANDROID`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That worked. Please see my updated question. I have updated this question, so that  everyone has a complete reference of the process in one question here. Thanks.

Comment: All good. Found the answer. I was using the --all flag incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

For the updated part of my question, please see below answer:

[Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)