# How to change GIT repo origin and keep all the branches

Tags: git

A repo on our server got corrupted and can't be saved. I'd like to use the cloned version of the repo on my PC and commit all its files and branches to a new repo.

(I have copied the entire folder of my repo on my PC to a safe location so I will have all the files if I make a mistake.)

What I've tried:

1. I have created a repo on our server
2. `git remote set-url origin url-of-the-new-repo`
3. `git add .`
4. `git push`

This pushed all my files and history to the new repo. Unfortunately though all the branches are missing, only the "master" exists. The commit history is there and I see that where did we do branches and merges, but can't go back to those commit because suddenly I will get a detached head.

The questions is: how could I push all the files and branches in my local repo to the new origin?

Comment: Checkout to that detached point of merge, create new branch there and push to new origin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)

Comment: @Tenatus yes that helps. The only issue is that the git push --all doesnt push the branches I have deleted locally from sourcetree, so using a little bash script. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @Justinas To create a branch from an old commit one doesn't need to check it out: `git branch <name> <committish>`

Comment: Just push the other branches, no need to have local branches for that: `git push new-remote old-remote/branch1:refs/heads/branch1 old-remote/branch2:refs/heads/branch2`. With a little bit of bash-fu you could create a  bash big-1-liner to push all branches in a single go

Answer (score 1):

`git push -u origin --all` should do it. The `--all` option is the important bit to push all branches. Be careful when pushing to a project where others are working on other branches, in those cases, you would only want to `git push` on the branch you are currently on.

Comment: Despite the name, `--all` does not actually push _all_ refs, only those under `refs/heads` (branches). To actually push all refs, you'd want to use `--mirror`.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks!