# How to fork a code repository in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I must clone a repository into a new code repository within Palantir Foundry. But the only option available is to create a new branch or clone to my local workstation. Neither is an option for me. Is there a way to fork - or clone a repository into a newly created repository?

I tried creating both a bash script and a Python script within a new code repository that clones the old repository but there is no way to execute the scripts within Palantir Foundry's Code Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone the source repository locally, you can add the fork repository as a remote.

Then you can push code from the source repo to the fork repo, as described here: [Push local Git repo to new remote including all branches and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags)

For example:

```bash
git remote add my_fork <FORK REPO URL GOES HERE>
git push my_fork --all
```

Comment: Thank you, but we're not allowed to install Git on our government laptops. I did contact Vantage support and they said you could copy a branch to another repository within the Vantage GUI.