# Git GPG error signing tags

Tags: git, gnupg

gotOK I'm a bit of a rookie when it comes to Git. So I decided to read Pro Git by Scott Chacon. BTW great book, highly recommend it.

Anyway  got to the section about Signed Tags.
To sign a tag with GPG you must have a private key set up which I do.
However, when I ran:

```
git tag -s v1.6 -m "my signed 1.6 tag"
```

I got the following:

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\git>git tag -s v1.6 -m "my signed 1.6 tag"
gpg: error loading `iconv.dll': The specified module could not be found.

gpg: please see http://www.gnupg.org/download/iconv.html for more information
gpg: skipped "Name <name@gmail.com>": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
error: unable to sign the tag
```

So, I done what the error message told me to do and went to the link and followed the instructions. I copied iconv.dll to the folder that contained gpg.exe (\Git\bin). Ran the command again and got:

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\git>git tag -s v1.6 -m "my signed 1.6 tag"
gpg: skipped "Name <name@gmail.com>": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
error: unable to sign the tag
```

EDIT:

When I try and list my secret keys I get this error???

```
Name@NAME-PC ~
$ gpg --list-secret-keys
gpg: keyblock resource `c:/Users/Name/.gnupg\secring.gpg': file open error
gpg: keyblock resource `c:/Users/Name/.gnupg\pubring.gpg': file open error
gpg: fatal: c:/Users/Name/.gnupg: directory does not exist!
secmem usage: 0/0 bytes in 0/0 blocks of pool 0/32768
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could initialize your gnupg environment (secret key) with a gpg GUI like [gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/), following [this tutorial](http://www.coresecure.com/v5/gnupg.html), or (more up-to-date) the official gpg4win documentation "[Gpg4win for Novices](http://gpg4win.de/handbuecher/novices.html)".

[image: private key creation]

Note that this [blog post](http://dllhell.net/2012/03/30/on-signing-git-tags-on-windows/) add the following caveat:

> I installed Gpg4win, which installs a nice GUI for managing keys and the GPG command line interface.
> My ignorance of the process was clear as I repeatedly attempted to use the GUI (GNU Privacy Assistant – Key Manager) to create my key. **That GUI appears to create valid keys, but wherever it stores the related key part files is not where the GPG command line expects to find them**.

(Note: probably on `C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\gnupg`, with a directory was named `gnupg` and not `.gnupg`)

> Instead, be sure to use the command line client. Start with:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

> **If key creation fails, you might manually need to create the directory `c:users<USER>.gnupg`, which GPG will apparently not do on its own**.

```
cd C:\Users\Name 
mkdir .gnupg
xcopy C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\gnupg .gnupg
```

> The errors that I was seeing along the way were

```
gpg: no writable public keyring found
```

> and:

```
signing failed: secret key not available
```

---

Note: once your gnupg is in place, if you still have the error message, do [add the the (gnupg) `key-id` you want to use when signing your tag](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/secret-key-not-available-unable-to-sign-the-tag-tp1500685p1517291.html):

```
git tag -u 'key-id' -s -m "some comment" some-tag
```

---

As noted by [roguib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14142644/roguib) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876817/git-gpg-error-signing-tags/16877329#comment122709836_16877329), you will need, if you [want to see that tag on the remote side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309):

- `git push --tags`
- or, since Git 2.4.1 and `git config --global push.followTags true`, a simple `git push` is enough.
- and, still with Git 2.4.x, you can add `git push --atomic`, to make sure everything was indeed pushed (or nothing will).

Comment: If you still want to use the gui, or already created a key with it, you can link the directories via

    MKLINK /D C:\Users\NAME\.gnupg C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\gnupg

Comment: In case you want to see tag in GitHub as well, remember to push it with `git push --tags <remote>`.

Comment: @roguib Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Actually, with `git config --global push.followTags true`, a simple `git push` would still be enough.