# How To Import Tags Into Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I've just converted our repository from github to an internal gitlab. I started by getting a bare local repository and I have been able to get a new master into gitlab.

In my local repository, git tag shows a list of tags that I had on github. But none of the tags are showing up in gitlab.

I have GitLab 6.6.0.pre fe6c534.

So I how do I import my tags into gitlab?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should push those tags to your remote gitlab:

```
git push --tags
```

By default, `git push` pushed only commits, not tags.
(See "[Push git commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309)" for more on that)