# Git tags detached from master branch

Tags: git, github

I have created and pushed tags on a git repository:

```
git push --tags
```

The problem is it hasn't pushed it to `master` branch (as I thought it would) but created detached instead. So on GitHub, my `master` branch still points to previous commit.

Is there a way to have the commits related to the tags be pushed into `master` branch instead?

Btw, when I'm working on `master` branch, what would be the correct way to create and push tags onto the master branch without having it detached from the `master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push --tags` only pushes tag, not the branches.

Complete the operation with a `git push` (or `git push -u origin master` if you never pushed master before)

If you want to push everything in one command (git 1.8.3+):

```
git push --follow-tags
```

See "[Push git commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309)".

Comment: Thanks! I thought push --tags pushed branches as well.

Comment: Jippi!! `git push` did the trick. Probably, I shall read a bit about tags and branches...