# git push --tag keeps commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

When pushing to the master, I read that it is recommended to use:

```
git tag -a <tag name> -m <message> ; git push --tags
```

I added a new tag, and pushed the changes to the master, now I modified another file and want to push it to the master with the same tag.

I do: `git push --tags -f`, I get "Everything up-to-date" message. but when I do: `git status` I still see that: "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits"

why it is so ? what I have to do to add the new changes to the tag ?

Comment: ‘*push it to the master with the same tag*’ What?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push git commits & tags simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push with

```
git push --all
```

and if there are new tags, with:

```
git push --all; git push --tag
```

Not `git push --tags`. `--tags` will push all references of tags, not commits on the master branch. I don't know where you have read this advice, but tagging constantly is not really encouraged. Normally you tag **when you have a new release of your software**. In other words a major milestone. Not for an ordinary commit.

Furthermore I would strongly discourage using the `-f` (also known as `--force`) flag (fully) automatically. If the repositories are out of sync, it is better not to force your commits over the shared repository. If there are warnings, you must try to resolve them, not overrule these warnings immediately.

General advice is to learn to use a tool instead of following a few steps without realising what is going under the hood.

**EDIT**:

You probably received an error when you added the tag a second time:

```
fatal: tag 'foo' already exists
```

(with `foo` the name of the tag). As the statement says, you can't simply tag with the same name twice. `git push --tags` commits content **up to that tag**. Since you assigned the tag with a previous commit, you will push up to that commit, not the latest. You can do a few things:

- Use a different tag (recommended) and push with `git push --tags`;
- Reuse the tag and force tagging `git tag -f -a <tag name> -m <message>`. In that case the old tag is removed. And `git push --tags` will work. The problem is that usually tags are used to specify a release. Users might say: *aha, the latest release is `release-2.3`, I don't have to update the software* whereas the new `release-2.3` is different from the old one. Annotating with `release-2.3-fix0` might make them aware you fixed something.
- Use `git push --all` to push the commit up to the heads of all branches.

**Background**

You can see your commit graph like:

```
A -- B -- C -- D
         /
      <tag>
```

If you call `git push --tag`, it will synchronize `A`, `B` and `C` because that's the last commit under the supervision of `<tag>`. If you retag, the tag will be assigned to `D` instead.

Comment: this is what I am doing, tagging for every release, this time I had a bug fix and wanted to include it in the same tag ...
maybe I am missing how tags really work, I understand that they are snapshot of the master at specific time ( release time ... ).
I though that push --tags pushes the changes and tag them with the available tag.
so what does really push --tag does if I did git push --all and all my changed are pushed ?

Comment: @FoadRezek: but if you tag for the second time, you will get a fatal error, because the tag already exists. A tag is a reference to a commit (like google.com is a reference 216.58.210.46). If you push with `--tags` it will push **up to that tag**. But since your tag is placed a few commits behind (the new commit is not retagged), you push thus only up to the commits behind the head.

Comment: @FoadRezek: see uopdated anser.

Comment: The `--all` flag is completely unrelated from the issue. If you want to push all your branches, then use `--all`, but if you want the default behavior of `push` (configured by `push.default`), then don't use `--all` and let `git push` do its job.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy: please read the edit. At that point it was unclear that the OP was working with tags...

Comment: I did read the edit, and I still think there's no relation between `--all` and the problem. You can just drop the `--force` even in your edit.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a `git push`, several things happen:

1. Some commits are sent to the remote repository
2. The remote branch (e.g. `master` on the remote machine) is updated to point to the latest commit
3. The remote-tracking branch (e.g. `origin/master` on the local machine) is updated to reflect the change on the remote branch

By specifying `--tags`, you modify the behavior to update only the tag reference (plus some other references you may have specified on the command-line, but you didn't). If you tagged the latest commit, then this commits and all its ancestors were pushed, but you didn't go through steps 2 and 3 above. As a consequence

- Users looking at your remote repository will see the tag, but will see the branch some commits behind
- Since `git status` uses the remote-tracking branch to determine whether you're ahead of the remote, it will tell you that you are ahead of the remote.

The simplest solution is to run two pushes:

- `git push` to push your branches as usual (as specified by `push.default`, i.e. push the current branch to the configured upstream if it has the same name with recent Git)
- After creating a tag, `git push --tags` to push your tags (will take almost no time since the commits are already pushed, Git just needs to create the tag on the remote repository)

If you want to do both at the same time, then see the answers to the question [Push git commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously).

Note that there's no reason to create a tag for *each* of your pushes. Usually, people create tags only for releases.

Answer (score 0):

git `push --tag` only pushes the tag, not the commits.