# Git commit doesn't show on repository when a tag is moved towards it on push

Tags: git, github

I recently pushed a commit and moved a previous tag onto it with the push.

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "made changes and moving previous tag to this commit"
git tag -a {previous-tag} -f
git push --tags -f
```

When using `git log` it shows the commit, but at my git repo page, it doesn't show the commit. How can I fix this?

Edit: The most recent commit shown on my Github page is the commit that the tag was originally on.

Edit 2: Also, Composer pulls in the correct commit (the newer one that the older tag was pushed to). I'm not pulling dev-master.

**Update:**

I'm not sure what the problem was but I pushed a test commit (without moving tag) and suddenly the previous two commits that did not show are showing up now (timestamp of the problem commit was hours ago).

Comment: HEAD refs won't get pushed, meaning that you ONLY push the tag only not code.

Comment: No, pulling the package via composer pulls the most recent commit (the actual most recent commit). Edit: also I'm not pulling dev-master, I'm pulling that tag version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unless you are using `git push --follow-tags` (git 1.8.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309), you have pushed only the tag, not the branch HEAD.

A pull will pull that tag, and reference that commit.
But until you push the branch HEAD (which you did by pushing a test commit), you won't see that tagged commit on the remote repo.

Comment: Thanks! I've run the command and will be using it in the future.