# Because my files do not go up in my repository tag?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to upload a tag to a specific commit but the tag goes up and the files do not go up with it.

**What should I do?**

**I am inside my X branch and from there I used the following commands:**

```
git tag -a vfv.1.0.0-homo COMMIT_TOKEN
git push origin fv.1.0.0-homo
```

Comment: Tag is a reference to commit. You have to push your tagged commit first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git commit doesn't show on repository when a tag is moved towards it on push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707986/git-commit-doesnt-show-on-repository-when-a-tag-is-moved-towards-it-on-push)

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs 
What command should I make to upload the tag and the files in it?

Comment: You push your commits: `git push <remote> <branch>`, and then create a tag and push it: `git tag -a <tag> <sha>`, `git push <remote> <tag>`.

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs 
This time it was, funny .. It was what I was doing .. Insert this as an answer that I will give you star.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've moved my comments into answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag is a reference to a commit. You have to push your commits first.

This is the workflow to push commit(s) with a tag:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
git tag -a <tag> <sha>
git push <remote> <tag>
```

Comment: Note that `git push <remote> <tag>` will actually send the commit. It just won't update the *branch name*. You can do both in a single push by running `git tag -a <tag> <tag-arguments>; git push <remote> <branch> <tag>`.

Comment: Also, there's now the `--follow-tags` option on push, you can `git tag -a $tag master; git push --follow-tags origin master` and it'll find all the new tag objects pointing into the new history and send them along.