# GitPython create and push tags

Tags: python, git, gitpython

In a python script, I try to create and push a tag to origin on a git repository. I use gitpython-1.0.2.

I an able to checkout anexisting tag but no way to find how to push a new tag to remote.

Many thanks

Answer (score 19):

```
new_tag = repo.create_tag(tag, message='Automatic tag "{0}"'.format(tag)) 

repo.remotes.origin.push(new_tag)
```

Comment: useful links: [git.Repo.create_tag](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.create_tag) and [tutorial](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#advanced-repo-usage)

Comment: this doesn't push the tag for me. I see it locally, but not remotely

Comment: It's better to use `new_tag.name` here.

Answer (score 8):

To create a new tag using gitpython:

```
from git import Repo
obj = Repo("directory_name")
obj.create_tag("tag_name")
```

To push to remote

```
obj.remote.origin.push("tagname")
```

Comment: this doesn't push the tag for me. I see it locally, but not remotely

Answer (score 2):

```
tag = repo.create_tag(tagName, message=mesg)
repo.remote.origin.push(tag.path)
```

`tag.name` may be conflict with your local branch name, use `tag.path` here.

Answer (score 1):

[Git supports two types of tags: lightweight and annotated.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging/#_creating_tags)
So in GitPython we also can created both types:

```py
# create repository
repo = Repo(path)
# annotated
ref_an = repo.create_tag(tag_name, message=message))
# lightweight 
ref_lw = repo.create_tag(tag_name))
```

To push lightweight tag u need specify reference to tag `repo.remote('origin').push(ref_lw )`, but in annotated u can just use:

```py
repo.remote('origin').push()
```

if configuration `push.followTags = true`. To set configuration programmatically

```py
repo.config_writer().set_value('push', 'followTags', 'true').release()
```

[Additional information about pushing commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below snippet code to create a tag and push it to remote. You may need to handle exceptions by adding try ... catch block on each git operation.

```
repo = git.Repo(os.path.abspath(repo_path)
repo.git.tag('-a', tagname, commit, '-m', '')
repo.git.push('origin', tagname)
```