# git push --all --tags: incompatible

Tags: git, git-push

When I try to push all branches and tags to a remote, git emits the following error:

```
# git push origin --all --tags
fatal: --all and --tags are incompatible
```

However, this works:

```
# git push origin refs/heads refs/tags
Everything up-to-date
```

---

Questions:

1. Why git names push-all-branches `--all` but not `--branches` or `--heads`? `git push origin --all` only pushes branches, not all refs. What's the philosophy behind such naming? Does this mean tags are really 2nd-class citizens in a Git repo?
2. **Why git doesn't allow the use of both `--all` and `--tags`?**

---

PS. I know there's a `--follow-tags` option. I know pushing all tags is not recommended by some people, but this thread is not about that.

---

`man git-push`:

> --all
>
> Push all branches (i.e. refs under refs/heads/); cannot be used with other <refspec>.
>
> --tags
>
> All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line.

Comment: I'm not sure how the documentation could be clearer that `--all` cannot be used with `--tags`. There is no *why*, someone just coded that in the ancient past, and now it behaves that way.

Comment: upvoted for the `git push origin refs/heads refs/tags` that I didn't figure out yet but is quite convenient.

Comment: @torek *someone just coded that*, seriously there isn't something technical behind that? That sounds to me like bread and milk are incompatible. If you don't allow people to do something you should give a valid reason. Otherwise they deserve the freedom. Git is obviously free software.

Comment: I think the problem dates way back to before references were systematized. Someone made `git push --all` mean *all heads* and since the Git folks are reluctant to change the meaning of arguments, we're stuck with it. It's quite inconsistent, but then, so is `git rm --cached` vs `git diff --staged`. They did eventually change `git add -A` so if you start a campaign, perhaps Git 3.0 or 4.0 will have some more sane option(s).

Comment: I did find below the technical issue torek alluded to: does this answer your question?

Comment: @VonC *it is implementation related perhaps*

Comment: @Cyker Yes, that is what the bug found by Jeff King (mentioned below) suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message "`--all and --tags are incompatible`" comes from [`builtin/push.c#cmd_push()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12039e008f9a4e3394f3f94f8ea897785cb09448/builtin/push.c#L604)

This was introduced by **[Marek Zawirski](https://github.com/zawir)** in [commit b259f09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b259f09b181c6650253f2ab60f5375d3ff8e3872) in August 2008 (Git v1.6.1-rc1):

> ### Make push more verbose about illegal combination of options
>
> It may be unclear that `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` and/or explicit refspecs
>   are illegal combinations for `git push`.
>
> Git was silently failing in these cases, while we can complaint more properly about it.

In 2008, Marek was [implementing `git push` in JGit](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=121460442905215&w=2), and [proposed that patch mentioned above](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=121890953115497&w=2), adding:

> I forgot about this one, it was reported long time ago.
>
> It seems that it may be really unclear what's going on with git failing on `$ git push --tags --all` and similar, as it is implementation related perhaps.

While [it is possible to configure a remote](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=121021757220073&w=2) with:

```
[remote "origin"]
  push = refs/heads/*
  push = refs/tags/*
```

[Jeff King](https://github.com/peff) [discovered a bug](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=121022017823071&w=2) (kind of deadlock) which is probably why this patch exists.

> The sender does a "tellme-more" and then waits for a line back.
>   The receiver gets the tellme-more, but never says anything else, presumably
>   because he doesn't have that commit (because master is ahead of any
>   tags).

In short, pushing branches and tags separately seems easier to support than pushing them together.

See more with "[Push git commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309)", with `git push --follow-tags`, or `git config --global push.followTags true`.