# Azure devops doesn't commit tags from local repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a Git/Visual Studio C# project on my local machine. I like to tag version changes and releases. The problem is that when I use Sync in Visual Studio to push changes to the remote Azure DevOps repo none of my tags survive the trip. If I use `git push --tags` in Git Bash the tags show up in Azure.

Any ideas how to make Sync do this as I will inevitably forget to push them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio this is just as disconnected as usually in git, where you first push your changes and than the tags as well.

Check the Team Explorer in Visual Studio and go to 'Tags' to push your tags from there.

Comment: You can also read here on how to configure Git to do that, but that is then only for your local git environment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously

Comment: I had no idea this was Git's default behaviour, though I can understand why it is. Thanks, Today I  Learned...