# git push --tags not pushing master?

Tags: git

I'm migrating some versions of a project manually into git, so I have done the following:

1. created an empty project on remote then did a clone in an empty folder and checked I was on master and it said branches up to date with origin/master
2. copied my first version into the folder
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "xxx"`
5. `git tag -a "Vx.x.x" -m "xxx"`

Then I repeated the above for all my versions and when I had finished all versions I ran: `git push --tags`

when I checked the server all tags were there with all files and full history, but master was still the same empty project with just the readme.md file, and on checking git status it said I was 6 versions behind.

So I ran `git push` and it was ok after that.

Did I do something wrong in my steps as I presumed after each commit master would be updated and push with --tags would push everything.

thanks.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push): `--tags`: "All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line." - If you didn't explicitly mention any refspecs, `git push --tags` pushes **only** tags. It will push enough commits to be able to store the tags, but it will not update remote branches.

Comment: ah, thanks. So there's no single command to push everything? Shall I answer my own question or do you want to promote this to an answer?

I don't think there is but I saw this saying you can automate it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously

Comment: You could try `git push --tags --all`. You can answer your own question, I'm between meetings here so don't have much time.

Answer (score 2):

From comment:
As per the documentation: --tags: "All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line." - If you didn't explicitly mention any refspecs, git push --tags pushes only tags. It will push enough commits to be able to store the tags, but it will not update remote branches.

You can automate it via:
[Push git commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to do

```
git push --all --follow-tags
```

to push all branches with tags

I'm assuming that you want to push everything because you didn't mention the branch in your push command