# Pushed tag is not coming up on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created a new tag with command
`git tag -a v1.0 -m "Production Release"`.

And pushed the tag to remote by `git push origin v1.0`

It was successful and I got the below response.

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 662 bytes | 662.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://bitbucket.org/project/repo.git
 * [new tag]         v1.0 -> v1.0
```

But still when I browse the Bitbucket commits, I cannot see this tag.
It was supposed to be shown right next to the last commit.
Am i missing any steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your git status when you have setup the tag: you might have been in a [detached HEAD mode](http://pstauffer/gitlab-webhook-receiver).

That would explain why the last commit of a *branch* (as opposed to any commit in a detached HEAD) would not have received the tag.

---

The [OP jinil-cs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6818184/jinil-cs) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627867/pushed-tag-is-not-coming-up-on-bitbucket/61628005#comment109014096_61628005):

> As you suggested, `git status` showed me
>
> ```
> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
> ```

That is not a detached HEAD situation, but point to the other reason you don't see a tag along a branch HEAD: you have not push your branch yet.

> I did `git reset --hard origin/master` since I don't need my local changes.

OK, that is a bit dangerous, as others might make their last commits invisible (there are still in the `git reflog`), but in your case, that would work.

> Then I deleted the remote and local tags.
>
> ```
> git push --delete origin v1.0 
>   git tag -d v1.0
> ```
>
> Created the same tag and pushed it again!

---

I mentioned in [April 2013 the Git 1.8.3 `push` option `--follow-tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309), suggested by [Daemon Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125110/daemon-painter), which would indeed have pushed non-pushed commits *and* the new tag, making it visible to your remote branch HEAD.

But since you did not need your local commits to be pushed, your solution is still valid.

Again: a `git status` to check the situation locally remains a good first step to understand the discrepancy between what is done locally and visible remotely.

Comment: As you suggested,
`git status` showed me
`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.`

I did `git reset --hard origin/master` since i don't need my local changes. 

Then I deleted the remote and local tags.

`git push --delete origin v1.0`
`git tag -d v1.0`

Created the same tag and pushed it again!

Comment: @jinilcs Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added some additional information.