# How to avoid triggering builds from git in codemagic

Tags: git, codemagic

Is there a way to skip the github build? The problem is that my builds are automatically triggered when pushing to a branch, but after merging to the main branch and triggering the build automatically.I want to upgrade the flutter version of the application, make a commit and tag, push changes to the same branch. The problem is that after pushing a new version of the build from the codemagic itself to current branch, the codemagic triggers build again and I get a recursion. Does anyone know a working way? I have tried all of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously), also tried to disable trigger builds on tags and push changes from script with tag at the same time [Codemagic build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmmTH.png) [Codemagic script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Zxb.png)[Branch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Utvm.png).

Codemagic build script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

    set -e # exit on first failed command
    set -x # print all executed commands to the log
    
    #if [ "$FCI_BUILD_STEP_STATUS" = "success" ]
    #then
      
      #bump code version
      perl -i -pe 's/^(version:\s+\d+\.\d+\.\d+\+)(\d+)$/$1.($2+1)/e' pubspec.yaml
    
      #create a tag and publish
      v=`grep 'version: ' pubspec.yaml | sed 's/version: //'`
      version="dev-$v"
    
      git commit -m "Bump version to $version" pubspec.yaml 
    
      git tag -a -m "Bump app version" $version 
    
      git push "https://user:$GITHUB_SSH@github.com/repo/mobile" --follow-tags
      #fi
```

Comment: Please fix your question so the links and images work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add "skip ci" or "ci skip" to the commit message.

It's standard for Codemagic and other continuous integration services.

Comment: I thought it's was work only for gitlab, thanks!