# First version after tag push has patch equal to 1 and not 0. Why?

Tags: git, github-actions, gitversion

I am using GitVersion with Github Actions with main branch.

When a new tag is pushed to main branch, e.g. v2.0.0, I want to increase the patch:

```
2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, ...
```

I have the following Github workflow:

```
name: Project
    
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:

  setup:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      version: ${{ steps.versioning.outputs.semVer }}

    name: setup

    steps: 

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Dotnet
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
 
      - name: GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v1
        with:
          versionSpec: '5.x'

      - name: Versioning
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v1
        id: versioning
          
  build:

      // Remaining workflow code
```

And I also have the gitversion.yml settings file:

```
mode: Mainline
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^main$
    mode: Mainline
    increment: Patch
    is-mainline: true
```

And this is where the files are located in my project root:

[image]

**Question**

I pushed the tag v2.0.0 and after it I pushed the code to main branch.

The first version I got was 2.0.1 ... Why not 2.0.0?

I also tried to push the tag v2.0 but the first version is always 2.0.1.

Why? Is there a way to make 2.0.0 the first version after pushing the tag?

Comment: Rename `gitversion.yml` to `GitVersion.yml` and move it to the root of your repo. See https://github.com/GitTools/actions/blob/main/docs/examples/github/gitversion/execute/usage-examples.md#inputs for `configFilePath`.

Answer (score 1):

As I just mentioned on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78223581/6309), the GitVersion config file default name is `GitVersion.yml`, not `gitversion.yml`.

In your case, it is best to specify the full path (from the root of your repository)

```
steps:
  # gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v1.1.1 action omitted for brevity.

  - name: Determine Version
    uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v1.1.1
    with:
      useConfigFile: true
      configFilePath: myVersionConfig.yml
```

Here that would mean a `myVersionConfig.yml` in the root folder.

To achieve 2.0.0 as the first version after pushing the tag, you would need to make sure the commit triggering the version calculation is the same commit the tag points to, or you would need to reconsider the workflow to adjust when and how you apply tags versus when you expect version increments.

Maybe pushing the [commit and tag together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309) would help. (`git push --atomic origin <branch name> <tag>`).