# Why git doesn't push tags by default?

Tags: git, git-tag

The default behavior of Git is *not* to push tags from a local repository to an associated remote one. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2988182/671013) it is explained how to change this behavior for a single repository.

My question, is **why** is this the designed behavior of Git? In particular what are the cons of setting on automatic push of tags?

Comment: `tag` is a **snapshot** of the repository. My guess is that it shouldn't be updated upon push, unless, you explicitly would like it to be published.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2988182/654952

Comment: @yuwang: I already linked to this answer. There is a comment there posing the same question which is still unanswered...

Comment: it's **well described** IMO, see the quoted: "This is very much intended behaviour, to make pushing tags explicit. Pushing tags should be usually conscious choice."

Comment: I didn't see the answer you provided before I made first comment. anyway I think the link you provided **already** answered your question.

Comment: @yuwang: Not really. "should be usually..." is sort of general. What can go wrong if you *do* push *all* tags...

Comment: @Dror ending with hundreds of tags in the upstream repo, most of them having no interest. As described in my answer below.

Comment: I don't get it. What are these hundreds of tags that people would be creating locally that have no meaning upstream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you consider the tags of any large project ([kernel linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags), [git itself](https://github.com/git/git/tags), ...) you would see tags in the *hundreds*.

A *Distributed* VCS is all about **[publication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563917/6309)**: what do you want to push?
Everything? All the time?

Pushing *all* tags can pollute the tags space from the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166).

With the current behavior, you keep the control of what you are publishing to the upstream repo, for others to see.

---

Note that since git 1.8.3 (April 2013), the `git push --follow-tags` can help you push commits and their associated tags in one command.

See "[Push git commits & tags simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309)".