# How to only push a specific tag to remote?

Tags: git

Is there a command like `git push --tag tag_a`? I only found `git push --tags`.

Comment: Documentation indeed doesn't seem to be very strong here.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2988182/456814).

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
git push origin tag_a
```

Alternatively (mainly to solve tag/branch name clashes), you could use:

```
git push origin refs/tags/tag_a
```

Comment: What if the `tag_a` is the same name with a branch name?

Comment: Did you try `git push --tags tag_a`?

Comment: `git push refs/tags/tag_a` and `git push --tags tag_a` both seem don't work.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. `git push remote_name refs/tags/tag_a` will work. I missed the remote name.

Comment: Is the answer correct now?

Comment: @dirkk When without remote name we cannot push at all. Why you edit it back?

Comment: Because your edit radically changed the answer and because it is incorrect in general. You can set a `push.default` (take a look at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), so this can work. However, you might want to add this information to the answer, which imho would add value to the answer.

Comment: Is it actually possible to have a tag with the same name as a branch in a local repo? How is the local repo supposed to resolve the ambiguity in such a case?

Comment: @YadSmood: Then I probably misunderstood and should revert my own edit as well.

Comment: @YadSmood: Your edit was indeed right, I made a very similar one now.

Comment: @Cupcake: Just tested. It works well. The local git is supposed to require the user to resolve the ambiguity by specifying `refs/tags/name` or `refs/heads/name`.

Comment: @dirkk: The former version of my answer didn't actually work (with a default setup at the least). `push.default` doesn't seem to make any change, here.

Comment: Just

`git push origin-name tag-name`

Answer (score 18):

As pointed out by [Pavel Šimerda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212493/456814), you can simply do

```
git push <remote> <tag>
```

I've added the specification for a remote `<remote>` so that the command doesn't depend on a user's [`push.default` configuration](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Here is a summary of the [relevant documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) that explains how to push a specific tag:

> ```
> git push [<repository> [<refspec>…]]
>
> <refspec>...
> ```
>
> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is…the source ref `<src>`, followed by
> a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`…
>
> The `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push…If
> `:<dst>` is omitted, the same ref as `<src>` will be updated…
>
> tag `<tag>` means the same as `refs/tags/<tag>:refs/tags/<tag>`.