# pushing private pod

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I am creating my own private pod. I have complete all step. But in last step when we call

```
pod trunk push AffleChat_msy1.podspec
```

We got error like

> [!] Source code for your Pod was not accessible to CocoaPods Trunk. Is
>   it a private repo or behind a username/password on http?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140396/unable-to-create-private-pod

Comment: Page not found. Can you please give the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is:

```
pod repo push [REPO_NAME] [POD_NAME].podspec
```

Before, you should consider that you need to tag your current version:

```
git tag ‘1.0.1’
```

Also pushing that tag.

```
git push --tags`
```

The `--tags` command pushes all tags, even unwanted. Push just one tag by: [How to only push a specific tag to remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212452/how-to-only-push-a-specific-tag-to-remote)

```
git push origin 1.0.1
```

See this [medium article](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03) to get a good overview about how to update private pods.