# Error with pod spec lint

Tags: git, cocoapods, podspec

I want to public a framework.

I have created a pod spec in my framework directory, fill pod spec information, then type `pod spec lint`

But it gives me error:

```
-> KPImageView (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/khuong291/KPImageView.git
/var/folders/t5/rgq4j6cn7h79khx0xsftrjtw0000gp/T/d20161113-67362-1dxzrg4
--template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.0

Cloning into
'/var/folders/t5/rgq4j6cn7h79khx0xsftrjtw0000gp/T/d20161113-67362-1dxzrg4'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 1.0.0 to clone. fatal: Remote
branch 1.0.0 not found in upstream origin ) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error. [!] The
validator for Swift projects uses Swift 3.0 by default, if you are
using a different version of swift you can use a `.swift-version` file
to set the version for your Pod. For example to use Swift 2.3, run:
`echo "2.3" > .swift-version`.
```

my podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "KPImageView"
  s.version      = "0.0.3"
  s.summary      = "UIImageView with Ken Burns effect."
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/khuong291/KPImageView"
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT' }
  s.author       = { "khuong291" => "dkhuong291@gmail.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/khuong291/KPImageView.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'KPImageView/KPImageView/*'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like [CocoaPods issue 4871](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4871)

That error was because the *tag* 1.0.0 was not pushed.

[Don't forget to push tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2988088/6309) with `git push --tags`.