# Can I have private git tags that are not sent via a push?

Tags: git

If I tag commits that I am working on, then push changes to another repo, I understand that I can also be pushing tag objects. Can I create tags that are not pushed? Are e.g. lightweight tags never pushed, but tag objects always are?

Comment: Sure, don’t ask for them to be pushed. What’s your question?

Comment: git tag and push documentation aren't specific on what the implementation does -- I didn't find explicit statements that tags are private until a push --tags or --all is done. Elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787797/cannot-commit-a-git-tag)  Jakub Narębski mentinos that "if you create new commits on your branch, and then push (so there is something to transfer), git should detect all new tags that point to commits that are present after push on remote side, and push them too." Is that incorrect? I'm seeking explicit information about when tags are or are not transmitted.

Comment: @Vincent Scheib - Look at my answer and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988088/do-git-tags-get-pushed-as-well where the same person you are quoting says a different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are created in `.git/refs/tags/` and anything under `.git/refs` can **potentially** be pushed, based on the flags that you add to push or other commands. With that said,

> By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote
>   servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server
>   after you have created them.

http://progit.org/book/ch2-6.html

As per @Vincent Scheib's comment asking about the below quoted comment in another question:

"if you create new commits on your branch, and then push (so there is something to transfer), git should detect all new tags that point to commits that are present after push on remote side, and push them too."

It is not valid. It is applicable when fetching though, but wrongly thought to be applicable for push.

Comment: Thx, due to mixed signals verified by experimentation: Tags (of any kind) are not pushed unless explicitly named. From other Q, "git push <remote> tag <tagname>" and "git push <remote> --tags" are the explicit options.

Answer (score 5):

Tags aren't pushed automatically you have to manually push them.

On the other hand `git push --all` and `git push --tags` push every tag so you have to be careful.

---

**Resources:**

- [git push](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

**On the same topic:**

- [Git global tags— evidently bad, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793781/git-global-tags-evidently-bad-but-why)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `git push --all` or `git push --tags`. When you create a **public** tag, use the command:

```
git push origin TAG_NAME
```